# Can small-sized businesses have offices nationwide?

Tags: linkedin

I was wondering if small-sized businesses (less than 200 employees nationwide) can have offices across the nation.

I saw a job ad on LinkedIn and then researched the company. They claim to have around 300 employees but say they have offices in 12 different locations on their website?

That equates to about 25 employees per office, and something doesn't seem to add up.

Do businesses actually work this way?

Comment: Yes there are businesses that work that way.

Comment: I think it depends on the type of business this company does, but I see no reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Depends on the business. If you sell or service something, then physical presence in the customer's area may be important, in which case, sure it might make perfect sense to have offices all over the place with just a few employees in each office.

Comment: "If it happens it must be possible." And it does sometimes happen. Note too that some of the "offices" may be individuals working remotely, or working on customer sites.

Answer (score 13):

Absolutely. The most obvious example is sales offices. I know many companies that have sales offices with one to four people in each one. I've also worked in a field service office back when I used to do tech work where I was the only one in the area.

Just think of any role where you really don't need a large staff but may need a "presence" in the area and you can have an office there.

Comment: I think you're missing the *real* most obvious example: stackexchange itself...new york, oregon, london, etc, etc.

Comment: Previous employer in the UK - had 80 people based out of Basingstoke, 5 in Birmingham and 5 in Manchester.